# Reducing the zoom in to 85% when VS2010 starts up

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi is there any way in which the zoom in level changes to 85% whenever VS2010 loads a project.
I find doing this procedure every time I load a project or a different page/file.I would like the default level to be 85% rather than 100%

Comment: Duplicate of: [Visual Studio 2010 default zoom level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771750/visual-studio-2010-default-zoom-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it on startup, but check out [Presentation Zoom](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a7a0b57-7059-470d-bcfa-60ceb78dc752/).

If you zoom in on one page, the other pages will respect the new setting. It only persists while the Visual Studio is open, so you'd have to do it once every time you open it.