# Zooming in Visual studio 2012 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, zooming

I'm unable to find setting a dynamic Zoom value in terms of % in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate edition.

As i'm aware of mouse scroll and keyboard shortcuts: `CTRL + SHIFT + ,`  and `CTRL + SHIFT + .`

But i couldn't able to find the % value of the zoom for which i'm zooming either in Status bar or in any Menu Options.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771750/visual-studio-2010-default-zoom-level may help

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Look at left bottom corner....

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this extension
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71870f0e-87bb-4a5f-8abd-e8e5e0ccb900