# How to set permanent Zoom factor in Visual Studio Editor 2012 tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2012, zooming

If I set the zoom of a tab to 120%, then when opening new tabs, Visual Studio 2012 should open them with a 120% zoom factor and not 100% (the default).

But when reopening, Visual Studio the Zoom Percentage should be preserved (120%).

Is there is any way to solve the issue?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 preserves the zoom percentage even when opening files, solutions or VS itself.

Comment: not in SSDT/BIDS SSIS design canvas with HiDPI (4K) displays.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you are simply zooming so the text in your editor is bigger, then why not just increase the font size?

Open TOOLS -> OPTIONS, under the 'Environment' tab select 'Fonts and Colors', and change the font size to whatever you want.

--edit--

As @Anovative pointed out in his comment and answer below, there is now a way to set default zoom within Visual Studio 2013 (and subsequent versions I'd assume).

Comment: why? because on a high DPI screen sometimes a zoom level of something like 97 or 95% percent (you can type anything in you want) can make the font pixels 'snap' into a more pleasing place than changing the font size which doesn't respect fractional font sizes

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Fair enough, but I'm guessing for most people's use case this is a sufficient solution.

Comment: it was for me too :-) until I got a Surface pro and couldn't find any fonts I liked until I tweaked the percentage

Comment: I appreciate this answer because, like the original asker, I was asking this question simply because I wanted text to be smaller so I could see more.

Comment: There are too many font sizes to have to go change them all. If you want the zoom level to stick because you sometimes work on a bigger monitor, you probably don't want to change all those fonts back and forth each time you move to another computer.

Comment: Exactly. I use 8 pt font, don't like 7 pt, but set my zoom to 96%, which gets me somewhere inbetween.

Comment: @core how do you set that 96% for all windows?

Comment: I'll tell you a good one, if I zoom **in** one mouse wheel notch I can see up to line 56, whereas in 100% I see up to line 52. If I change the font size from 10 to 11, I lose lines and I can see only up to 45. So that is why one wouldn't want your solution. zoom was definitely implemented in a weird manner which makes it different than font size. And desirable for me since it makes characters bolder and lines vertically tighter.

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer it is wrong per the question asked. In VS 2013 you can set the default zoom for all editor pages. Each time I start VS my zoom level at the bottom is set to 95% for all editor pages. Existing ones and new ones I open. After closing VS and reopening it still starts me off at 95% on all editor tabs, that's for all solutions too. I have provided the answer that it seems the OP is requesting. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33660000/673846

Comment: @Anovative Updated my answer to refer to your answer.

Answer (score 25):

Go to **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates** > then get the extension

> VSCommands for Visual Studio 2013 ...if you're using VS2013

Then **Tools** > **VSCommands12** > **General** > click the button **Open Configuration**.

Then close out of the Options window and in the **VSC - Config** tab that should be open go to the **Zoom** option and set your default zoom level.  This will apply to all editor tabs.  You can still zoom in or out of individual tabs as desired. But your default zoom will be preserved even after closing VS and will be restored upon starting VS.

Comment: that's a great extension besides the zoom enhancements - thanks for sharing.

Comment: There is a TON of great stuff in this extension, well worth taking the time to dig through it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got set zoom default in vs 2013 by following steps: Tools > VSCommands > Options > IDE Enhancements > Zoom

Answer (score 17):

This extension solve the problem
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71870f0e-87bb-4a5f-8abd-e8e5e0ccb900

Answer (score 1):

These tools do not solve the whole problem, but may help:

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71870f0e-87bb-4a5f-8abd-e8e5e0ccb900?SRC=VSIDE
- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a7a0b57-7059-470d-bcfa-60ceb78dc752/

Maybe this also helps: 
[Visual Studio 2010 default zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771750/visual-studio-2010-default-zoom-level)

Considering this [Default Zoom](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/33f37e07-0783-42d7-859c-1823536be7d9/) question, the whole problem is not solvable (for VS up to 2010) :-/. From my point of view this is a really missing feature.

Edit: Solve the Post from Aditya Patil the problem?